# Full calender long events to be displayed without the long bar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have full calender that gets data from json file , and displayed as in the image.
Is it possible , instead of long event being streched accross muliple dates , I want them to displayed in dates individula cells as the one bellow on the image .
I just need a guide in the right direction . Any help much appreciated .
[image]

Comment: If you make it a recurring event rather than single long event then yes, I would expect so.

Comment: Its not recurring its a single long event , the problem is if I have more than 20 bookings in one day the whole thing becomes messy. I have gone throught the docs and I'm yet to find a function that i can tiwck to achive this.

Comment: `Its not recurring its a single long event `....then it makes logical sense for it to cross over all the days. It's continuous, so it shows continously. If you make it separate on each day, then people will think it is a series of separate events which start and end individually on each day. Therefore, what you are asking for doesn't really make sense - which is why you can't find a way to do it.

Comment: P.S. 20 bookings per day in month view will start to look busy / messy (however you want to describe it) no matter what type of events they are. You can control it a bit with the event popover settings though - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-popover

Comment: Thanks but I had tried popover before , I need to split them into days cell  so its not going to cut here . I will  probably try altering the data source.

Comment: `I need to split them into days cell `...that isn't logical, as I already explained. And it's irrelevant to the user of the popover, anyway as far as I can see.